# How to apply the "auto next post load" scroll on my website?

Tags: wordpress, autoload, autoscroll

A newbie here...I am trying to apply a system that allows readers to "infinitely" scroll down to the next posts after finishing a single post so that they don't have to manually click them.

(Like this website does:

https://dancingastronaut.com/2020/12/maceo-plex-confronts-racism-and-diversity-in-latest-single-cinemax/)

I tried the “auto load next post” plugin, but it didn’t work on my theme :(.

I’m currently using the Amphibious theme developed by templatepocket.
https://wordpress.org/themes/amphibious/

This is the biggest part I’m having a struggle with, and I think my website is good to go once it’s applied. I hope someone can help me out here!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to edit your single post template, usually `single.php`, and add a trigger when a user scrolls past that point.

```
<?php $gpNextPost = get_next_post(); ?>
<div class="gp-infinite-scroll" style="display: none;"><?php echo $gpNextPost->ID; ?></div>
```

Then call an AJAX function to load next post's content and also replace the URL in the browser's address bar.

Here's a rough example:

```
function gp_infinite_scroll($pid){
  if (is_single()) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
          var footerPos = $('footer').last().position().top;
          var pos = $(window).scrollTop();

          if (pos+(screen.height*4) > footerPos) {
            if ($(".gp-infinite-scroll").first().hasClass('working')) {
              return false;
            } else {
              $(".gp-infinite-scroll").first().addClass('working');
            }

            var gpNextPostId = $(".gp-infinite-scroll").first().text();
            var data = {
              'action': 'gp_is',
              'gpNextPostId': gpNextPostId
            };

            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
              $(".gp-infinite-scroll").first().replaceWith(response);
            }, 'html');
          }

          // Update new URL
          var currUrl = $(".gp-post-header").first().attr("url");
          var currTitle = $(".gp-post-header").first().attr("title");

          if ($(".gp-post-header").length > 1 && history.pushState) {
            for (var i=0; i<$(".gp-post-header").length; i++) {
              var trigger = $(".gp-post-header").eq(i).next().position().top;
              if (pos+(screen.height/2) >= trigger) {
                currUrl = $(".gp-post-header").eq(i).attr("url");
                currTitle = $(".gp-post-header").eq(i).attr("title");
              }
            }
          }
          if (location.href != currUrl) {
            history.pushState({}, currTitle, currUrl);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>

  <?php }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'gp_infinite_scroll' );

function gp_infinite_scroll_callback() {
  if (isset($_POST['gpNextPostId']) && $_POST['gpNextPostId']) {
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array('p'=>$_POST['gpNextPostId']));
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        // Change to your own Single Post template file
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );
      }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
  }
  wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_gp_is', 'gp_infinite_scroll_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_gp_is', 'gp_infinite_scroll_callback' );
```

This code is untested but it should get you going. If the above seems too much for you then you migh try some of [the related plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/infinite+scroll/).